# Matrix problem with MathJax plugin

Tags: plugin-mathjax

My code LaTex matrix is as follows:
[latex]\begin{matrix}
জাহাঙ্গীর খান\\
কালা জাহাঙ্গীর\\
৩২\\
বাদল খান\\
নোয়াপুর
\end{matrix}[/latex]

But the output says:

> ```
> Formula does not parse.
> ```

Even following code is not working.
[latex]\begin{matrix}
নোয়াপুর
\end{matrix}[/latex]

I have used Unicode Bangla here as matrix elements.

Comment: it works for me, did you write it in HTML mode or visual mode?

Comment: @birgire, visual mode.

Comment: This is my code in text mode. [latex]\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
2
\end{pmatrix}[/latex] The output is: http://i.imgur.com/ZKqHjRG.png

Comment: Try it in HTML mode without newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Either do not use any linebreaks in the LaTeX code, or (what should be preferred) add the following to your `functions.php` file:

```
remove_filter('HOPEFULLY-THERE-IS-A-FITTING-FILTER-IN-THE-SHORTCODE-FUNCTION', 'wpautop');
```

Iff there is such a filter, though.